# Mutable Variables can not be used in request.security() but sometimes we are forced to use them. Is there a workaround? V5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

We have a boolean variable for an event:

```
SomethingHappened = (high > close) and (low < high) //
```

… which is if wanted to be limited to a certain timeframe then `request.security()` is our savior:

```
SomethingHappenedOnlyIn5Min = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "5", SomethingHappened)
```

But e.g. in the following case, our `SomethingHappened` event can **only** be a mutable variant:

```
//'n' is where our scope array starts from, if not in the current 0 offset
for ArrayOfOffsets = 0 to k
    SomethingHappenedInSeries := SomethingHappenedInSeries and/or SomethingHappened[n+ArrayOfOffsets]
```

**In this case, our `request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "5", SomethingHappenedInSeries)` function won't work. Is there a way to avoid this trap?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason `request.security()` does not allow for mutable variables is because they get changed during the script's calculations based on the calculations done in the global scope of the script. For example, a mutable variable `a` can be 0 at the beginning and then get mutated to `a := 1` based on the `bar_index` of the main chart.

This doesn't fly in the `request.security()` because the whole expression passed to security is calculated separately on the symbol/timeframe passed to it. You can't request `a` from `security()` because it is explicitly tied to the context of the symbol currently open on your chart, because the variable is mutated based on the condition that is calculated on the current chart.

The way to work around this is to use user-defined functions. If you wrap everything you need in a function, you can pass mutable variables to `security()` and it will calculate them properly. This is because the function is self-contained, it can be extracted without any ties to the main symbol on the chart and calculated inside of the `security()`.

In your case, this would look something like this:

```
fun() =>
    SomethingHappened = (high > close) and (low < high) 
    SomethingHappenedInSeries = false
    for ArrayOfOffsets = 0 to k
        SomethingHappenedInSeries := SomethingHappenedInSeries and/or SomethingHappened[n+ArrayOfOffsets]
    SomethingHappenedInSeries
    
SomethingHappenedOnlyIn5Min = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "5", fun())
```

As long as you wrap *everything* in a self-contained function that can be safely extracted into a different context, mutable variables are fine to be used in `security()`.

Comment: I failed to implement it. (It's not exactly the same situation because in this case, there's no such "series of event" thing in the context, just a mutable variable to use in req.sec()…) Would you please look at the question I've just submitted about it? Thank you very much. :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72175465/failed-to-avoid-mutable-variable-error-message-on-request-security-what-did